# Random Variable X and Y has a joint probability density function.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Random Variable X and Y has a joint probability density function.

$$f_{X, Y} (x, y) =\begin{cases} 
cxy& 0 \leq x \leq y, 0 \leq y \leq5\\ 
0 & \text{otherwise }\\
\end{cases}
$$

(a) Find $f_{Y | X}(y | x)$

(b) $P(Y \leq 4 | X = 3)$

---

$(a)$

$$f_X(x) = \int_{0}^{5} cxy dy = cx/2(y^2)\bigg|_{0}^{5} = \frac{cx25}{2}$$ with support $0 \leq x \leq y$

$$f_{Y | X}(y | x) = \frac{cxy}{cx25/2} = \frac{2y}{25}$$

$(b)$

$$f_{Y, X}(y | X=3) = \frac{2y}{25}$$

$$\int_{0}^{4} f_{Y, X}(y | X=3) dy = \int_{0}^{4} \frac{2y}{25} dy = \frac{2}{50}\left(y^2 \right)\bigg|_{0}^{4} = \frac{16}{25}$$

Apparently, this is wrong, why so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pdf only has support for $y>x,$ so actually $$ f_X(x)  = \int_x^5cxy\;dy.$$

Comment: Also do the same for (b). @Basbas

Comment: so, x to 4 for b?

Comment: @Basbas No. What is the support of $f(y\mid X=3)?$

Comment: Oh. So, 3 to 4.

Comment: @Basbas yes, the support of $f(y\mid x)$ is $(x,5).$